# Video Panel Position Is Missed

Tags: html, video, download, panel, owl-carousel

I am using a `<video />` tag inside an **owl carousel**, but the download panel position is missed, as you can see it's shifted to the left, and sometimes is shifted to the top left or bottom left.

I have tried to give the video the following CSS styles, but it did not work.

```
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

The panel position works well outside the owl carousel, but inside it's missed.

I did not notice that the video takes any styles from the owl carousel styles, so I can not figure where the problem is!

Here is a [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/weamadel_dev/pen/mdWjEaN), which shows a wrong download panel position on media less than 1600px.

[image]

Comment: Would you please post full code or post e jsfiddle link. Otherwise it's difficult to understand what's happen.

Comment: I have added a CodePen demo in the question, thank you.